# output a file at server as it is in html from php

Tags: php, linux, bash

I have a file err.txt at my apache2 server and I want the file to be viewed from web page as it is.
The problem is that php is not outputting whitespaces before the first non-space character of line.Like it should output:
This is the error:

> curr_code.c:4:3: error: missing terminating " character

```
printf("Hello DIT\n');
      ^
```

but it is outputting:

> curr_code.c:4:3: error: missing terminating " character

This is the error:

```
printf("Hello DIT\n');  
^
```

I used `file_get_contents()`,`exec('cat err.txt',$out)`,and many more..
plz suggest apt sols.

Comment: i got the answer the output from ajax request should be put in pre tag instead of p tag. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would be the way the browser is displaying the content, since it will think it is HTML. To resolve this, try changing the content type for the output;

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
```

This will need to go *before* you output the content